# select customer names who have not transacted since November 2021

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL Table with the columns `Name`, `Transaction Date`, `Order ID` and `Order Amount`. I want to know which Customers have not done a single transaction since November 2021.

I am new to SQL and trying something like

```
SELECT distinct(C_Name) 
from Orders 
where T_Date <= '30-Nov-2021'
```

But how do I make sure that these customers have not transacted since December?

I'm working on MySQL, but cannot figure out how this can be achieved.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: If they have never transacted, do you want to see them?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT R.C_NAME
FROM ORDERS R
GROUP BY R.C_NAME
HAVING MAX(R.T_DATE)<'2021-12-01' --1 DECEMBER
```